# Using subtypes and domains for a tree layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, domains, subtype

I have a point layer in ArcGIS Pro with trees, set up a table with 2 fields Family and Tree species, including domain lists. So dFamily = "Quercus" (oak) and "Salix" (willow) and dSpecies = Quercus robur, Quercus petrea, etc. Some families like willow have a lot of species, so that list is long. When i add a new point/tree on the map and select field Family = Quercus, I would like in the field Species ONLY the Quercus species and not the whole list of all the tree species. How to do that? Using domains and subtypes, but how?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same question. Here’s a Esri training link with sample data and the USFS tree code list that my help you.

https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/assess-urban-tree-health-using-contingent-values/

https://github.com/tjgionet/FIATreeSpeciesCodes/blob/master/FIATreeSpeciesCode.csv

Please let me know if you’ve found any helpful information on the subject.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).